# AWS Api Gateway rate limit for Coginto user

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

My application allows users to register for accounts using AWS Cognito. They can then consume protected resources accessible through API Gateway.

Can I impose rate-limiting constraints for Cognito user whoever tries to exploit the endpoint?

e.g.

limit: 10 req/sec

user-1 and user-2 submits concurrent requests

user-1: 5 req/sec
user-2: 7 req/sec

I don't want the 2 req (5 + 7 - 10) from user-2 to be constrained by the limit.

API Keys and Usage Plans don't seem to cover the mentioned case, or am I missing something?